Use JQuery to format date in a paragraph to a different format
I have a page with blog posts on so I can't adjust the output (no access to server-side code) but I want the date in Nov 4, 2022 format.
The HTML looks like this:
<span class="post-time">
  <p>04/11/2022</p>
</span>

I know my date format is MMM D, YYYY but I cannot seem to get the code to output anything.
I have tried the following codes and can't seem to figure out how to get the new date to output:


$(document).ready(function() {
  // Variation 1:
  var post_date = $(".post-time1 p").text().format('MMM D, YYYY');
  $(".new-date p").text(post_date);

  // Variation 2:
  $(".new-date").val($(".post-time2 p").formatDate('MMM D, YYYY', new Date()));
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="post-time1">
  <p>04/11/2022</p>
</span>
<span class="post-time2">
  <p>04/11/2022</p>
</span>




What framework or plugins do you use that has format and formatDate? Your code does not work primarily because the format and formatDate do not exists in "raw" jQuery - do you perhaps use a datePicker? Also p is not a valid child of a span

@mplungjan thanks for the comment. Unfortunately, the HTML structure is dictated by the builder software so I cannot adjust the p and span unless I use code, right?
(this is built on the Simvoly platform).
So my struggle here is trying to work with the HTML & CSS that their platform spits out and using CSS / JQuery to achieve the look and feel I want.
In this case, I'm duplicating the site over from a different platform and the date looks bad as is on Simvoly. So I'm trying to get it to go from the raw 04/11/2022 to Nov 4, 2022.
Any other ideas? Thanks again.

The answer should work if you change the selectors to match your HTML

Here is a possible solution for your query.
Hopefully it can help you.


$(document).ready(function() {
  const time = new Date();
  const options = { month: 'short', day: 'numeric', year: 'numeric' };
  const formattedDate = time.toLocaleDateString('en-US', options);
  $(".post-time p").text(formattedDate);
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="post-time">
  <p></p>
</div>



Result:


When you click the button marked [<>] in the editor, you get the possibility to format your code.

There is no easy method to format Date by itself. I would advise creating a simple function to handle it.


$(function() {

  function stringToDate(strDate) {
    //Parse String into parts
    var parts = strDate.split("/");
    var dy = parts[0];
    var mo = parts[1];
    var yr = parts[2];
    return new Date(yr + '-' + mo + '-' + dy + 'T12:00:00Z');
  }

  function formatDate(dt) {
    var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
    var year = dt.getFullYear();
    var month = months[dt.getMonth()];
    var day = dt.getDate();
    return month + " " + day + ", " + year;
  }

  // Variation 1:
  var post_date = $(".post-time1 p").text()
  $(".new-date1 p").text(formatDate(stringToDate(post_date)));

  // Variation 2:
  $(".new-date2 p").text(formatDate(new Date()));
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="post-time1">
  <p>04/11/2022</p>
</span>
<span class="new-date1">
  <p>04/11/2022</p>
</span>
<span class="post-time2">
  <p>04/11/2022</p>
</span>
<span class="new-date2">
  <p>04/11/2022</p>
</span>



